# python помощь дописать код

Tags: python

Не могу дописать, что я не так делаю !

```
from itertools import permutations

# Задаем список слов и постоянное слово
words = ["acquire", "ankle", "hungry", "always", "viable", "artwork", "arctic", "youth", "farm", "arctic", "youth"]
fixed_word = "outha"  # Замените "постоянное_слово" на ваше постоянное слово



def generate_combinations(words, fixed_word):
    # Генерация всех перестановок слов
    word_permutations = permutations(words)

    i = 0  # Счетчик для подсчета общего числа перестановок

    # Открываем файл words.txt в режиме записи
    with open("words.txt", "w") as file:
        # Проходим по каждой перестановке
        for permutation in word_permutations:
            # Формируем строку, объединяя слова и добавляя постоянное слово в конце
            line = " ".join(permutation) + " " + fixed_word + "\n"

            # Записываем строку в файл
            file.write(line)

            # Увеличиваем счетчик перестановок
            i += 1

    # Выводим общее количество перестановок на экран
    print(f"Общее количество перестановок: {i}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_combinations(words, fixed_word)
```

Я не могу дописать

1. Так как файл получается большой, мне нужна функция "ставить на паузу" (выключить) и чтобы с того места начинал работать словарь.
2. Нужен код "постоянное_слово", которое не будет меняться
   fixed_word = "outha"  # Замените "постоянное_слово" на ваше постоянное слово  Это последнее слово а нужно что бы любое слово "постоянное_слово"
   Нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог в любой колонке изменить слово на "постоянное". Как в крайней колонке. А затем, вернуть все назад.

Comment: Очень интересно, но ничего непонятно. Что у вас на входе? Что вы хотите получить на выходе? Где чёткое описание задачи? Всё это должно быть в вопросе.

Comment: 1. Так как файл получается большой, мне нужна функция "ставить на паузу" (выключить) и чтобы с того места начинал работать словарь.
Нужно дописать код, или исправить

Comment: 2. Если получится, сделать нужно что бы не менялись слова, как последние скрипте. (fixed_word = "outha")
   И так же что я их бы мог включать. Как остановить так и включить.
вроде так опесал

Comment: Частично понятно, но всё-равно не очень. Ваш вопрос скоро закроют, судя по голосам. Постарайтесь всё же понятнее описать задачу. А главное непонятно - зачем вам делать из этого файл? Генератор позволяет в любой момент получить нужный кусок данных, нигде их не храня при этом. Ну получите вы файл примерно 3Гб размером, дальше вы что с ним делать будете, зачем это всё?

Comment: Генератор позволяет в любой момент получить нужный кусок данных, нигде их не храня при этом.  Я с ним не работал.
 а то что получается 3 гб  при деться разбивать, если кнопку не получится сделать паузу" (выключить)

Comment: Вы можете считать комбинации с помощью `enumerate`, запоминать последний сгенерированный номер и когда нужно будет продолжить просто пропустите все комбинации до этого номера включительно. Перебираются комбинации довольно быстро, если с ними больше ничего не делать.

Comment: Сложно для меня....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151329/discussion-between-sup0man-and-crazyelf).